# Restriction of a quotient map to its inverse image is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

If $q:X\to Y$ is a quotient map. Is it true that $q|_{q^{-1}(B)}:q^{-1}(B)\to B$ is also a quotient map for any subset $B$ of $Y$.

It seems that it is not true but i'm not getting any counter example. can anyone help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems true to me ... doesn't it suffice to check that $\big(q\big|_{q^{-1}(B)}\big)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $q^{-1}(B)$ whenever $V$ is open in $B$?

Comment: I think we should check that if $\big(q|_{q^{-1}(B)}\big)^{-1}(V)$ is open in $q^{-1}(B)$ then $V$ should be open in $B$.

Comment: @ Greg Martin what you said is always true because $q|_{q^{-1}(B)}$ is continuous.

Comment: aha, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample:**

Consider $X=[0,2]$.
Define the equivalence relationship:

$x \sim y$ if and only if $x=y$ or $x \in A$ and $y \in A$ where $A=\{0\} \cup ]1,2]$.

Let $Z=]0,1] \subset X$ and define $Y=X/\sim$.

If you consider $q : X \to Y$ the natural quotient map then taking $B=q(Z)$ you have your counterexample.

**Proof**

You should infact verify that $q^{-1}(B)=Z$ and that is $q_{|Z}$ is not a quotient map. I will prove only the second statement.

If $q_{|Z}$ is a quotient map then $U=]\frac 1 2,1]$ is in the form $q_{Z}^{-1}(C)=U$ for an opportune $C$ and it is an open set of $Z$.

Thus there should exists an open set $V$ full and such that $U=Z \cap V$.

Then, because $1 \in V$ and $V$ is full and open, $0 \in A \subset V$. Thus we would have that there exist $0 < x < \frac 1 2$ such that $x \in V$ which is impossible.

Comment: Thm 3.26 in [these notes](https://people.math.osu.edu/carr.520/files/2_Quotient_Spaces_and_Adjunction_Spaces.pdf) sheds some light on when this *is* true. $A:=q^{-1}[B]$ is a typical *saturated* set of $X$, and the restriction will be quotient when $B$ (and thus $A$) is open or closed or when $q$ as a map was open or closed.

Comment: Thankyou for sharing these notes